# Can these Band-gap specifications be attributed to a Half-Semiconductor material?

Tags: vasp, band-structure, spintronics

A ***Half-Semiconductor*** is a material with a *`narrow`* band-gap for one spin channel and a *`wide`* band-gap for the other channel.
Knowing that for this material :

$E_{gap}(up)$ = 0.9609 eV

$E_{gap}(down)$ = 2.4974 eV

*Can I consider the spin-up gap as narrow, and the spin-down as wide and call it  a Half-Semiconductor material ?*

Comment: I would say to find an actual source for this cutoff, but [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narrow-gap_semiconductor) suggests 1.11 eV or lower as a narrow bandgap.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good starting source but as you have said I must find a real scientific source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- For the up-spin channel, you can absolutely consider it as a semiconductor; for the down-spin channel, you can consider it as an insulator (may someone also consider it as a semiconductor, just different conventions). Thus, you can say your material is a half-semiconductor (HSC). (HSC is a semiconductor in one spin channel but an insulator in the other spin channel.)
- One more thing you should check is the band alignment (don't mix the HSG and bipolar magnetic semiconductors (BMS)), seeing (d) and (f) below:

[image]

- Ref: https://academic.oup.com/nsr/article/3/3/365/2236578?login=true
- PS: As @Tristan Maxson said, it's hard to identify insulators (with a large bandgap) and semiconductors (with a moderate or small bandgap) with a definitive gap value.
- Finally how you obtained these gaps listed above? DFT, HSE06, or GW? I suggest that you calculate them with HSE06 or GW. DFT usually underestimates the bandgap of the semiconductors. If the GW gap of the up-spin channel is below 1.5eV and the GW gap of the down-spin channel is above 3eV, then it must be classified into HSCs.

Comment: These results were obtained using GGA+U.

Answer (score 5):

I think you will be hard pressed to find a definitive answer, however I would say you are within reason to call it a half semiconductor.  Just be aware that this doesn't seem to be a well defined term and you may need to give the audience / reader a prompting on what you mean by half semiconductor.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right.